# How can Javascript or jQuery access my Django Models?

Tags: django

I have a little bit of jQuery on my page which needs to access one of my Django Models. Basically it's a form autocomplete, and it needs to look up values in my database.

I understand how to get values into a Django Template, but getting them into some Javascript code is confusing.

Is this possible? How can it be done?

Thank you.

Comment: as far as i know this is not possible, you need to pass values to template, and there is nothing confusing about that

Comment: @Tom Brock , Did you try the code??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link has everything you need. The code is properly written and easy to understand. You can use the values of your model/table to be auto populated in the input field. [Check from  this link.](http://flaviusim.com/blog/AJAX-Autocomplete-Search-with-Django-and-jQuery/)

```
    def get_Datas(request):
        if request.is_ajax():
            q = request.GET.get('term', '')
            Datas = DataModel.objects.filter(short_name__icontains = q )[:20]
            results = []
            for Data in Datas:
                Data_json = {}
                Data_json['value'] = Data.short_name
                results.append(Data_json)
            data = json.dumps(results)
        else:
            data = 'fail'
        mimetype = 'application/json'
        return HttpResponse(data, mimetype)
```

And use this in template,

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.8.18/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" media="all" />

    <div class="ui-widget">
      <label for="datas">datas: </label>
      <input id="datas">
    </div>
```

And the script would be:

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script> 
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(function() {
      $("#datas").autocomplete({
        source: "/get_Datas/",
        minLength: 1,
      });
    });
    </script>
```